# Bind to properties of property in viewmodel xamarin.forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a content view with several controls in it, which I want to bind to the properties of a property in the content view's code behind. The model is passed correctly to the content view, but the bindings are not updated.

The content view's XAML is:

```
<ContentView.Content>
      <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="clock" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Summary.MeetingsList}" />
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                <Image Source="meeting" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Summary.TotalMettings}"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">
                <Image Source="people"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Summary.People}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
```

The content view's code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SummaryControl: ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SummaryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Summary), typeof(SummaryModel), typeof(SummaryModel), new SummaryModel(), BindingMode.OneWay,
    propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        var view = bindableObject as SummaryControl: 
        view.Summary = (SummaryModel)newValue;
    });

    public SummaryModel Summary { get { return (SummaryModel)GetValue(SummaryProperty); } set { SetValue(SummaryProperty, value); } }

    public SummaryControl: ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The SummaryModel class:

```
public class SummaryModel
{
    public string TotalMettings { get; set; }
    public string People { get; set; }
    public string MeetingsList { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need another class as my viewmodel for the content view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forget to set the binding path

#### in ContentView

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
              x:Name="CustomView"  // set the name of view
             x:Class="xxx">
```

```
<Label Text="{Binding Summary.MeetingsList,Source={x:Reference CustomView}}" />
```